# Group rows in an associative array of associative arrays by column value and preserve the original first level keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping, associative-array

I have an array of subarrays in the following format:

```
[
    'a' => ['id' => 20, 'name' => 'chimpanzee'],
    'b' => ['id' => 40, 'name' => 'meeting'],
    'c' => ['id' => 20, 'name' => 'dynasty'],
    'd' => ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'chocolate'],
    'e' => ['id' => 10, 'name' => 'bananas'],
    'f' => ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'fantasy'],
    'g' => ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'football']
]
```

And I would like to group it into a new array based on the id field in each subarray.

```
array
(
    10 => array
          (
            e => array ( id = 10, name = bananas )
          )
    20 => array
          (
            a => array ( id = 20, name = chimpanzee )
            c => array ( id = 20, name = dynasty )
          )
    40 => array
          (
            b => array ( id = 40, name = meeting )
          )
    50 => array
          (
            d => array ( id = 50, name = chocolate )
            f => array ( id = 50, name = fantasy )
            g => array ( id = 50, name = football )
          )
)
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($old_arr as $key => $item) {
   $arr[$item['id']][$key] = $item;
}

ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Comment: @Herbert, I'm guessing writing to a non-existing id affects performance?  or does it fire off PHP warnings?

Comment: @SampleJACK: My mistake. At first glance I thought he was verifying that an id exists in `$old_arr`. Now that I examine it more closely, using `array_key_exists` doesn't add anything to this code. The result is exactly the same without it. In terms of performance: it calls a function on an array inside a loop which has to outweigh any performance hit you'd take from writing to a non-existent key, so I'd suggest dropping the whole `if()` block.

Comment: @Herbert: I had added it as I thought an error would be displayed if the error reporting threshold was too low. I tested it and doesn't seem to complain.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I have my error reporting cranked up to show _everything_ and, you're right -- no complaints. I didn't mean to insinuate that it was bad code in any way. SampleJACK brought up performance and, after thinking about it, it makes sense to drop it. In all honesty, I thought it was checking the ids on the inner arrays. _That'll teach me to read more carefully._ :p You still get my +1 for good code.

Comment: I added an answer for posterity to clarify what I've been talking about.

Comment: This technic leaves the grouping item in the data

Array
(
    [2019-04-05] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-04-05
                    [page_id] => 1
                )

Comment: To role model better posting behaviors for the benefit of Stack Overflow, please add an explanation to this code-only answer. @Tim

Answer (score 15):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   $newarray[$value['id']][$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($newarray);
```

piece of cake ;)

Comment: Probably equally easy to explain how your code works and why you feel it is the best technique to use.

Comment: But really, there is no new value to keeping this answer on the page.  This code-only answer (an exact duplicate of Tim's technique) was posted 10 minutes after Tim posted.

Answer (score 4):

The following code adapts @Tim Cooper’s code to mitigate `Undefined index: id` errors in the event that one of the inner arrays doesn’t contain an **id**:

```php
$arr = array();

foreach($old_arr as $key => $item)
{
    if(array_key_exists('id', $item))
        $arr[$item['id']][$key] = $item;
}

ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

However, it will drop inner arrays without an id.

E.g.

```php
$old_arr = array(
    'a' => array ( 'id' => 20, 'name' => 'chimpanzee' ),
    'b' => array ( 'id' => 40, 'name' => 'meeting' ),
    'c' => array ( 'id' => 20, 'name' => 'dynasty' ),
    'd' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'chocolate' ),
    'e' => array ( 'id' => 10, 'name' => 'bananas' ),
    'f' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'fantasy' ),
    'g' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'football' ),
    'h' => array ( 'name' => 'bob' )
);
```

will drop the 'h' array completely.

Comment: This is an "invented problem" -- not represented in the OP's question.  Probably better to find another question which poses this problem and post it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Arrays::groupBy()](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/arrays.html#groupby) from [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
$groupBy = Arrays::groupBy($array, Functions::extract()->id);

print_r($groupBy);
```

And result:

```
Array
(
    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [name] => chimpanzee
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [name] => dynasty
                )

        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40
                    [name] => meeting
                )

        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => chocolate
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => fantasy
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => football
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => bananas
                )

        )

)
```

And here are the docs for [Arrays](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/arrays.html) and [Functions](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that will take an array as the first argument and a criteria (a string or callback function) as the second argument. The function returns a new array that groups the array as asked for.

```
/**
 * Group items from an array together by some criteria or value.
 *
 * @param  $arr array The array to group items from
 * @param  $criteria string|callable The key to group by or a function the returns a key to group by.
 * @return array
 *
 */
function groupBy($arr, $criteria): array
{
    return array_reduce($arr, function($accumulator, $item) use ($criteria) {
        $key = (is_callable($criteria)) ? $criteria($item) : $item[$criteria];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $accumulator)) {
            $accumulator[$key] = [];
        }

        array_push($accumulator[$key], $item);
        return $accumulator;
    }, []);
}
```

Here is the given array:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => array ( 'id' => 20, 'name' => 'chimpanzee' ),
    'b' => array ( 'id' => 40, 'name' => 'meeting' ),
    'c' => array ( 'id' => 20, 'name' => 'dynasty' ),
    'd' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'chocolate' ),
    'e' => array ( 'id' => 10, 'name' => 'bananas' ),
    'f' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'fantasy' ),
    'g' => array ( 'id' => 50, 'name' => 'football' )
);
```

And examples using the function with a string and a callback function:

```
$q = groupBy($arr, 'id');
print_r($q);

$r = groupBy($arr, function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
});
print_r($r);
```

The results are the same in both examples:

```
Array
(
    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [name] => chimpanzee
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [name] => dynasty
                )

        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40
                    [name] => meeting
                )

        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => chocolate
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => fantasy
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => football
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => bananas
                )

        )

)
```

Passing the callback is overkill in the example above, but using the callback finds its use when you pass in an array of objects, a multidimensional array, or have some arbitrary thing you want to group by.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth to mention that you can also use php `array_reduce` function

```php
$items = [
    ['id' => 20, 'name' => 'chimpanzee'],
    ['id' => 40, 'name' => 'meeting'],
    ['id' => 20, 'name' => 'dynasty'],
    ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'chocolate'],
    ['id' => 10, 'name' => 'bananas'],
    ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'fantasy'],
    ['id' => 50, 'name' => 'football'],
];

// Grouping
$groupedItems = array_reduce($items, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['id']][] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, []);
// Sorting
ksort($groupedItems, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($groupedItems);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: This is not the desired result.  You have lost the original first level keys which are expected to become second level keys.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33697617)

Answer (score 0):

Because of how PHP's sorting algorithm treats multidimensional arrays -- it sorts by size, then compares elements one at a time, you can actually use a key-preserving sort on the input BEFORE restructuring.  In functional style programming, this means that you don't need to declare the result array as a variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7hEGN))

```
asort($array);
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($array),
        function($result, $k) use ($array) {
            $result[$array[$k]['id']][$k] = $array[$k];
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```

---

I must say that functional programming is not very attractive for this task because the first level keys must be preserved.

Although `array_walk()` is more succinct, it still requires the result array to be passed into the closure as a reference variable. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9iFUj))

```
asort($array);
$result = [];
array_walk(
    $array,
    function($row, $k) use (&$result) {
        $result[$row['id']][$k] = $row;
    }
);
var_export($result);
```

---

I'd probably recommend a classic loop for this task.  The only thing the loop needs to do is rearrange the first and second level keys. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YpU4K))

```
asort($array);
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $row) {
    $result[$row['id']][$k] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

To be completely honest, I expect that `ksort()` will be more efficient than pre-loop sorting, but I wanted to a viable alternative.