# PHP: Building an HTML Table from an Array with Repeated Entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a database table (built from a query) that lists member (called Troop), events, start date, and end date.  A member might be listed more than once in the table as they are associated with more than one event.

I want to build an HTML table that lists the member's name followed by each event they are associated with before going on to the next member, which may be a few items down in the array.

I was thinking about using a`foreach()` statement but could not get it to work. Any pointers on how I might accomplish this? Thanks!

```
while(list($Event, $Troop, $StartDate, $EndDate) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $return=$return . "<table>";
  $return=$return . "<tr>";
  $return=$return . "<th colspan=3>" . $Troop . "</th>";
  $return=$return . "</tr>";
  $return=$return . "<tr>";
    $return=$return . "<th>Event</th>";
    $return=$return . "<th>Start Date</th>";
    $return=$return . "<th>End Date</th>";
  $return=$return . "</tr>";
        //foreach ($Troop as $thisTroop) {
        $return=$return . "<tr>";
        $return=$return . "<td>" . $Event . "</td>";
        $return=$return . "<td>" . $StartDate . "</td>";
        $return=$return . "<td>" . $EndDate . "</td>";
        $return=$return . "</tr>";
        //}
  $return=$return . "</tr>";
  $return=$return . "</table>";
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Would it work if I built two lists, one as `list_a($Troop)` and the other `list_b($Event, $StartDate, $EndDate)`?

Comment: No error. That code works as it is, however, it lists the Troop each time instead of listing the Troop once followed by their events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this. It's necesary that the sql result is sorted by Troop.

```
$return = '';
$currentTroop = '';

while(list($Event, $Troop, $StartDate, $EndDate) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($currentTroop != $Troop) {
        $return .= "<table>"
        ."<tr>";
        ."<th colspan=3>" . $Troop . "</th>"
        ."</tr>"
        ."<tr>"
        ."<th>Event</th>"
        ."<th>Start Date</th>"
        ."<th>End Date</th>"
        ."</tr>";
    }

    $return .= "<tr>"
    ."<td>".$Event."</td>"
    ."<td>".$StartDate."</td>"
    ."<td>".$EndDate."</td>"
    ."</tr>";

    if ($currentTroop != $Troop) {
        $return .= "</tr>"
        ."</table>";
        $currentTroop = $Troop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I started experimenting with exactly that, but you solution is much more clean than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a multi-dimensional array with keys of Troops and group every records with the same Troop. And then use foreach() to loop the array and print out the information.

[Group array by subarray values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values)