# PHP split multidimensionl array into chunks of array where matches a value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one large multidimensional array, which I got from database with picture locations

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 01.jpg
            [album] => /images/beach
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 02.jpg
            [album] => /images/beach
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 03.jpg
            [album] => /images/home
        )
)
```

i am trying to split it into smaller arrays that match the albums, as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 01.jpg
            [album] => /images/beach
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 02.jpg
            [album] => /images/beach
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 03.jpg
            [album] => /images/home
        )
 )
```

what would be a good way to go about it? i am thinking of shifting the first value into a new array until I reach the end but there must be a more effective way.

Comment: You might construct the desirable structure while fetching the rows from database: `while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc()) { $result [$row['album']] = $row; }`

Comment: Both arrays are the same? Could you rephrase your Question, please?

Comment: Can you also add a query that you're retrieving the data with? It might be easier to sort it by albums in the time you're getting the data from the database. And also the code how you're constructing the data.

Comment: If you want to do it the more difficult way, here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new array using `album` as key, which you need to group with, and thereafter updated keys using [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) if needed.

```
<?php
$arrays = array
(
    '0' => array
        (
            'name' => '01.jpg',
            'album' => '/images/beach'
        ),

    '1' => array
        (
            'name' => '02.jpg',
            'album' => '/images/beach'
        ),
    '2' => array
        (
            'name' => '03.jpg',
            'album' => '/images/home'
        )
);
$results = array();
foreach($arrays as $array){
    $results[$array['album']][] = $array;
}
$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/569788

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```php
$albums = array();
foreach ($dbrows as $dbrow) {
    $albums[$dbrow['album']][] = $dbrow;
}
unset($dbrows);
var_dump($albums);
```

Comment: this block is unnecessary: `if (empty($albums[$dbrow['album']]))`