# Group elements in an Associative arrays without altering the squence

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have following array

```
[0] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 32
    [subscribedTo] => 20
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 11:01:20
    [videoTime] => 2017-11-11 10:54:44
    )
[1] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 30
    [subscribedTo] => 2
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:27:32        
    [videoTime] => 2017-11-10 21:43:03       
    )
[2] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 30
    [subscribedTo] => 2
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:27:32      
    [videoTime] => 2017-11-10 21:38:36        
    )
[3] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 31
    [subscribedTo] => 7
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:28:29        
    [videoTime] => 2017-10-26 12:41:23       
    )
[4] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 31
    [subscribedTo] => 7
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:28:29       
    [videoTime] => 2017-10-26 12:29:02
          )
[5] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 31
    [subscribedTo] => 7
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:28:29       
    [videoTime] => 2017-10-26 12:23:26
    )
[6] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 30
    [subscribedTo] => 2
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:27:32        
    [videoTime] => 2017-10-09 09:23:59       
    )
[7] => Array (
    [subscriptionId] => 30
    [subscribedTo] => 2
    [subscriptionDate] => 2017-11-11 10:27:32       
    [videoTime] => 2017-10-09 09:23:35        
    )
```

I want to group the rows based on subscribedTo such that the sequence does not change.
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values)
but it results in following sequence based on subscribedId:
**2,2,2,2,7,7,7,20**

What I am trying to get is:
**20,2,2,2,2,7,7,7**

Comment: Try this: Just remove the second parameter from the code in the answer you've found: ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); -> ksort($arr);

Comment: @OfirBaruch It gives same result with or without 2nd argument

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is a simple problem that has a simple solution: iterate over the input array and generate a new array using your grouping rules.

Comment: @axiac i have mentioned the my question the link to solution I tried and also the results of that

Comment: You didn't mention the expected output and how did **you** try to reach it. Programming doesn't mean copy-pasting code from the internet.

Comment: *the sequence does not change* - 20,2,2,7,7,2,2 ?

Comment: @axiac I didn't copy pasted I gave reference to what I followed

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first group equal indices and then merging

```
$arr = [];// this should be your array
$temp = [];

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    if (!isset($temp[$a[subscribedTo]])) {
        $temp[$a[subscribedTo]] = [];
    }

    $temp[$a[subscribedTo]][] = $a;
}

$arr = []; //reset the array
foreach ($temp as $t) {
    array_merge($arr, $t);
}
```