# PHP - Group Array by its Sub Array Value (Indexed Array)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to group array by its sub array value.

just came through this link.

> [Group array by subarray values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values)

But here sub array value having keys. In my case we don't have key. Only indexed keys. Below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14. Remarketing Bengaluru
            [1] => RM Web
            [2] => Ludhiana
            **[3] => Display Only**
            [4] => INR
            [5] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12. Other Search ROTN
            [1] => 01. Eye glass Shapes
            [2] => Tiruchirappalli
            **[3] => Search Only**
            [4] => INR
            [5] => 144
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10. Brand ROTN
            [1] => 03. Brand + Keywords
            [2] => Erode
            **[3] => Search Only**
            [4] => INR
            [5] => 24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11. Competitors ROTN
            [1] => 02. Titan Eye Plus
            [2] => Thoothukudi
            **[3] => Search Only**
            [4] => INR
            [5] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14. Remarketing Bengaluru
            [1] => RM Web
            [2] => Chandigarh
            **[3] => Display Only**
            [4] => INR
            [5] => 6
        )
)
```

Expected:

Needs to group above array with starred value. Eg. Need to group array with array indexed key **3**.

Grouped array should be like **Display Only, Search Only**

Comment: Can you post your source code

Comment: Not much in source code. Just fetching array from csv file.

$csvFile = file('new-report.csv');
$csvRecords = [];
foreach ($csvFile as $key => $line) {
    if($key > 2) {
        $csvRecords[] = str_getcsv($line, "\t");
    }
}

$csvRecords - this is the array i have added in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the solutions from the SO post you link to? A numerical index of an array *is* the key when it is like that.

Comment: Yes i tried, but it not working for my case.

Comment: It works exactly as GetSet described in the comment. You'd better post your array as PHP source code. You can do this with the var_export () function.

Comment: @jspit my php array.
array(
  array(
        "14. Remarketing",
        "RM",
        "Lu",
        "Display Only",
        "INR",
        "6"
    ),
    array(
            "12. Other",
            "Shapes",
            "Ti",
            "Search Only",
            "INR",
            "144"
        ),

    array(
        "10. Brand",
        "Brand",
        "E",
        "Search Only**",
        "INR",
        "24"
        ),

    array(
        "11. Competitors",
        "Titan",
        "Th",
        "Search Only**",
        "INR",
        ),
)

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution from [Group array by subarray values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values). I just replaced 'id' with 3.

```
$old_arr = array( 
  array( "14. Remarketing", "RM", "Lu", "Display Only", "INR", "6" ), 
  array( "12. Other", "Shapes", "Ti", "Search Only", "INR", "144" ), 
  array( "10. Brand", "Brand", "E", "Search Only", "INR", "24" ), 
  array( "11. Competitors", "Titan", "Th", "Search Only", "INR", "1"), 
);

foreach ($old_arr as $key => $item) {
   $arr[$item[3]][$key] = $item;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export($arr);
```

Result:

```
array (
  'Display Only' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => '14. Remarketing',
      1 => 'RM',
      2 => 'Lu',
      3 => 'Display Only',
      4 => 'INR',
      5 => '6',
    ),
  ),
  'Search Only' => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => '12. Other',
      1 => 'Shapes',
      2 => 'Ti',
      3 => 'Search Only',
      4 => 'INR',
      5 => '144',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => '10. Brand',
      1 => 'Brand',
      2 => 'E',
      3 => 'Search Only',
      4 => 'INR',
      5 => '24',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => '11. Competitors',
      1 => 'Titan',
      2 => 'Th',
      3 => 'Search Only',
      4 => 'INR',
      5 => '1',
    ),
  ),
)
```