# Convert array of arrays into the array of sub arrays of same elements in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array:

```
$arrays = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'main'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'main'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'main'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'main'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'main'
        ]
    ];
```

Convert this array of arrays into the array of sub arrays of same elements in php
i want following expected output:

```
  [
    [
      [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'main'
      ],
      [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'main'
      ],
      [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'main'
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'main'
      ],
      [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'main'
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

i have tried array map with array reduce but i didn't get my result.

Comment: This questions seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574857/group-array-by-subarray-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple foreach loop would do this quite happily

```
$arrays = [
    ['id' => 1,'name' => 'main' ],
    ['id' => 1,'name' => 'main'],
    ['id' => 2,'name' => 'main'],   
    ['id' => 1,'name' => 'main'],
    ['id' => 2,'name' => 'main']
];

$new = [];
foreach ($arrays as $a) {
    $new[$a['id']][] = $a;
}
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => main
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => main
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => main
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => main
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => main
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: @mickmacusa should I delete this now ?